# React Table is not loading via forEach Error

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-table

I am running into an error of which is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')"

It seems it is within my TableOne component.

Here is the code for my TableOne component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

export interface TableProps {
    columns: any;
    data: any
};

const TableOne:React.FC<TableProps> = ({columns, data}) => {
   

    const tableInstance = useTable({columns, data});

    const {getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow} = tableInstance;

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()} >
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default TableOne
```

As you can see, I am just making it a functional component and having props being able to be sent into the component so that it can be used for multiple datasets. This is the copy and paste code from the template code on the React-Table site.

In my Home Page I have the following code.

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react'
import Table from '../components/Table'
import {gql, useQuery} from "@apollo/client"
import TableOne from '../components/TableOne'

const style ={
    hero:`bg-green-500 w-full h-96 p-2`
}

const AllCategoriesQuery = gql`
  query {
    allCategories { 
      name
  }
  }
` 

const Home = () => {

  const {data, loading, error} = useQuery(AllCategoriesQuery, {
    onCompleted: data => {
        console.log(data)
    }
})


  const columns = useMemo(() => [
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: "name"
    },
  ], [data])
   
   
  return (
    <div className={style.hero}>
        Home123
        {/* <Table /> */}
        
        <TableOne columns={columns} data={data}  />
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I just simply past my apollo-client data into the prop of the , however when I run this it makes my whole app disappear. It doesn't just make the page go away but also other components that are outside of this page.

Any assistance would be great!

Edit: Screenshot of error

[image]

[image]

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: just added to the question

Comment: looks like your props (columns or data) may be undefined. can you console log both of them? it would also make sense to wait for your useQuery to execute before trying to render the TableOne component

Comment: When I comment out the TableOne Component and just do console.log the data and columns I get both the data and the Header/accessor data on it as well.

Comment: When I uncomment the TableOne Component, the data doesn't show up in the console, only the columns.

Comment: Yes because the data is asynchronous, so you need to wait for that to resolve before trying to render the TableOne component

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return (
    <div className={style.hero}>
        Home123
        {/* <Table /> */}
        
        {data && <TableOne columns={columns} data={data}  /> }
        
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Just added, everything loads except the table and then it goes blank again. I get the error saying data.forEach is not a function.

Comment: Then it sounds like the issue is a type error. Are you passing the correct data type to the useTable hook? Are both columns and data arrays?

Comment: I believe so, I added a screen shot of my data.